# Ceph-Mgr-Dashboard not working with Ceph Naultilus Release

Tags: ceph

I install ceph cluster with ceph-deploy tool. And I want to install ceph-mgr-dashboard that its removed from ceph-mgr modules. In the official ceph tell if you want to use ceph-dashboard must be installl ceph-mgr-dashboard package and enable its.

This package with apt install ceph-mgr-dashboard. But it don't do anything with its. This is very miserable for ceph document. There's instruction but can't use follow its.

Answer (score 2):

Install the dashboard rpm in all the mgr servers:

```
yum install ceph-mgr-dashboard.noarch
```

Generate self-signed certificate (**key point**, in my installations, dashboard does not run without certificate):

```
ceph dashboard create-self-signed-cert
```

Enable dashboard:

```
sudo ceph mgr module enable dashboard
```

check status:

```
sudo ceph mgr services
```

Comment: You can turnoff ssl on mgr with config command: `ceph config set mgr mgr/dashboard/ssl false`

Comment: Yes, that also works, but I'm not sure you want to have a tool that can destroy your ceph installation accesible through un-encrypted http. I also disabled ssl to check if dashboard worked and then found this way to make dashboard run with ssl.